# "Unexpected error occurred" getting When open FBWebDialog in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, sdk, sharing

I am sharing job Details to Facebook Friends, using the "**Message**" Parameter to post all content.

When I open `FBWebDialogbox FBWebDialogs presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:<#(FBSession *)#> message:<#(NSString *)#> title:<#(NSString *)#> parameters:<#(NSDictionary *)#>`.

I get the following error **"Unexpected Error Occurred. Please try again later"**. But when I post less content with with the message param the error did not occur.

I've already posted with more content using Graph API to My Wall. But now I want to change to post to friends, however that is not supported in the Graph API.

Can I get any tips or suggestions on for this? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Sam, Thanks for edit my question. It should be very clear to all.

Comment: Hi All,Why i did not get response from no one. Please Help me